# How can debug a browser.click()

Tags: nightwatch.js

I have the following test:

```
it('Verify clear button action', function (browser) {
    browser.waitForElementVisible('div#controls button[data-action="clear-all"]', WAIT);
    browser.click('div#controls button[data-action="clear-all"]', (result) => {
        console.log(result);
    });
    browser.pause(WAIT);
    browser.waitForElementNotVisible('div#alerts', WAIT);
    browser.waitForElementNotPresent('button#alert-icon', WAIT);
});
```

the button `button[data-action="clear-all"]` exist and the output of the click function is:

> {
>       sessionId: null,
>       state: 'success',
>       hCode: 347300413,
>       value:{},
>       class: 'org.openqa.selenium.remote.Response',
>       status: 0
>   }

however I know that this click is not completely happening because in the event listener never gets executed; however, the button gets "focus".

I'm using:

- selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1
- geckodriver-v0.20.1-linux64
- Firefox 63
- nightwatchjs v0.9.20

Comment: Can you tell me what does `WAIT` signify in the above code.

Comment: that's the amount of time nightwatch needs to wait for an element to show up, it has been set from 1000 to 16000 milliseconds